# Chromium and Google Account login

Tags: chromium

I've download Chromium 53.0.2745.0 for Mac and I've no success in login with my Google account. I type my email, my password and the login box just closes.

I tried different Google accounts, turned off two step auth and nothing.

Then I've installed 51.0.2683.0 via Brew and I finally got access. However, when I open the new one (53) I see "Account sign-in details are out of date."

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

[According to the documentation](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys), you need a Google API in order to use the most recent Chromium.

After you get the API key and the other information, run in the terminal:

```
launchctl setenv GOOGLE_API_KEY yourkey
launchctl setenv GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID yourclientid
launchctl setenv GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET yourclientsecret
```

The reason for this is: your pre-built Chromium needs to know what is your API. Without this, you are unable to use the Google Sync service

Answer (score 3):

> Following answer is based on [this excellent gist by cvan](https://gist.github.com/cvan/44a6d60457b20133191bd7b104f9dcc4) with modification to use `launchctl` as suggested by @leozera. All credit goes to them. I republish for visibility (it took me several hours to find original document).

1. Download [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium) or use Homebrew to install it:

   ```
    brew install --cask chromium
   ```
2. If you launch it, you'll notice a yellow disclaimer message appear as a doorhanger:

   `Google API Keys are missing. Some functionality of Chromium will be disabled.`  `Learn More`.
3. Clicking on that link takes you to the confusing [API Keys docs page](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys).
4. If you aren't already, subscribe to the [chromium-dev@chromium.org mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/chromium-dev). (You can just subscribe to the list and choose to not receive any mail. FYI: the Chromium project restricts the APIs to those subscribed to that group - that is, Chromium devs.)
5. Make sure you are logged in with the Google account associated with the email address that you used to subscribe to chromium-dev.
6. Log in to the [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/), and [select an existing project](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/projects) or press the "Create Project" button.
7. From the project's [**API Manager**](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library), select the [**Credentials**](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) tab in the sidebar.
8. Create a [**Browser API Key**](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/key?type=CLIENT_SIDE).
9. You'll see a modal with an API key. Copy and paste that somewhere.
10. Now create an [**OAuth Client ID**](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient).
11. After you complete all the steps and the "content screen," you'll be presented with a modal with your Google Client ID and Client Secret.
12. You'll need to set three environment variables. In the shell type:

    ```
    launchctl setenv GOOGLE_API_KEY yourkey
    launchctl setenv GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID yourclientid
    launchctl setenv GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET yourclientsecret
    ```
13. Quit chromium if you have it running (make sure to actually quit it, as it may be running in the even without any window opened, e.g. use task switcher `alt-tab` and `alt-q`).
14. Start Chromium using Spotlight (`cmd+space`) or Launchpad.

Comment: This is now called `chromium`, so the install command should be:

`brew cask install chromium`