# Chromium and Google Account log in failed because browser is not supported

Tags: google-chrome, browser, login, chromium

I made a tigervnc connection to my raspberry pi 4b and started the built in web browser which is chromium.

When I wanted to turn on Google Sync with my google account, the login went wrong signing in, telling me, that this browser is not supported. Googling at first offers quite very few findings for me.

Chrome is not available for armhf platforms, so I am stuck with chromium.

System: Raspberry Pi 4b with 4GB/32GB and dietpi as linux system installed

Answer (score 1):

above shouldn't work anymore after **March 2021** as google limit the user of API see https://askubuntu.com/a/1322565/37213 and https://blog.chromium.org/2021/01/limiting-private-api-availability-in.html

Comment: You mean below my own answer to my question! Thanks a lot for your hint, but how can I solve my issue, that I want to sync google accounts on my raspberry pi??

Answer (score 0):

The following two answers of a little different question helped me solving this issue plus the following steps, so thanks to these users [@leozera](https://superuser.com/users/598070/leozera) and [@Tad Lispy](https://superuser.com/users/195460/tad-lispy) :

[Two subsequent answers](https://superuser.com/questions/1080114/chromium-and-google-account-login#1080940)

(Please keep in mind, I cannot tell if these preceding steps are really necessary, because my issue now is solved. And especially the next steps take a significant amount of time, so feel free to start from the bottom before continuing with the steps despcribed in the link respective concluded in the following two steps).

To conclude:

1. Followed both answers and set environment variables in /etc/environment :

   ```
    GOOGLE_API_KEY=mygeneratedkeyonGoogleCloud
    GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID=mygeneratedclientidonGoogleCloud
    GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET=mygeneratedclientsecretOngoogleCloud
   ```

   which were automatically embraced by double quotes when exported.
2. I activated all API's, according to:
   [Chromium.org API-key Howto](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys)

With the build-in chromium even after reboot, nothing changed.

Finishing 2 steps:

But then I signed into [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590482/downloading-google-chrome-armhf/590497#590497) via my google account. After that I was logged in also in to my google account in the chromium and  could turn on the sync! Password completion works. More to test when I continue working.

This work took a full morning to complete and test.